# Why can't we just say that $\infty-\infty$ equals zero?

Tags: real-analysis, infinity

> Let be $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}x=A$  and   $\lim\limits_{y\to
>  \infty}y=B$.

Can be $A-B=0$?

If the answer is "no" , why?

And my other example:

> $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{x}{1+x^2}dx$

Why does this not equal zero?

I know this is an improper integral, and I know how solve this. But I don't think this makes sense.

We have a positive area A and a negative area B (with $A=-B$).

Why can't we just say that

> $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{x}{1+x^2}dx=0$

And my last example:

> $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2=A, \quad \displaystyle\sum_{b=0}^\infty b^2=B$

Here can we say that $A-B=0$? If "no", then why?

Comment: It's an indeterminate form as far as limit is concerned

Comment: Well, basically, if you bother giving a name to $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=A$ and define $A-B$, you may also want $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-g(x))=(\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x))-(\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x))$$ but unfortunately, $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x-x^2=-\infty\neq 0=\infty-\infty=\lim_{x\to\infty} x-\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2$$ "Then - you may ask - why don't we call $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2=\infty^2$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln x=\ln\infty$ et cetera?" Well, personally I don't see a substantial gain in doing that. In non-standard analysis I think they do something of sort, but I don't know it in the slightest.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar and  G.Sasstelli (I couldn't added you , like @)

Thank you very much.

Comment: For your consideration in some of the examples, consider that, for $a,b\in\Bbb R$, $$\int_a^b \frac x{1+x^2}\,dx=\ln\sqrt{\frac{1+b^2}{1+a^2}}$$ To illustrate the definitory issue of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx$ I invite you to consider the following three limits: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^n \frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx=\ ? \\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-n}^{4n}\frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx=\ ? \\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-n^2}^{n}\frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx=\ ?$$

Comment: Dear G.Sassatelli , thank you very much, for edit, for answer ,for interesting and for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. Two examples.

Observe that, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
(x^2+x)-x^2=x \to \infty
$$ whereas, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\left(x+\frac1x\right)-x=\frac1x \to 0.
$$ In each case you have an indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

if we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^3=\infty$$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty}n^2=\infty$$ then the difference goes to $$\infty$$

Comment: yep understand ,Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

The form $\infty-\infty$ is what is known as an indeterminate form. This means as limits are concerned, the limit $\infty-\infty$ does not have a value.

Comment: Understood ,thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Infinite often is not an intuitive concept, but when a function goes to infinity its important to consider how it quickly grow. For example if you take $f(x)=3^x $ and $g(x)=x$ when $x \to +\infty, \space $ both functions go to infinity but $f$ is "faster" than $g$ so in this case $3^x-x=f_1(x)\to +\infty$ when $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest answer to your question, without either sequences or limits, is that there exist *distinct* infinite numbers. The most commonly used extension of the real numbers to an ordered field is the field of hyperreals. If $H$ is an infinite hyperreal, then so is $2H$ or for example $H^2$ or $\sqrt{H}$, not to speak of $H+1$ :-)